# If $u_n \rightharpoonup^* u$ in $L^\infty$, does $\int u_n^+ \to \int u^+$?

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Let $\Omega$ be bounded.

Suppose that $u_n \rightharpoonup^* u$ in $L^\infty(\Omega)$ and $u_n \to u$ in $H^{-1/2}(\Omega)$ (that is negative a half, not a typo).

Does this somehow imply that
$$\int_\Omega u_n^+ \to \int_\Omega u^+$$
No idea how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this does not hold. Take $u_n = \sin(n\pi x)$ on $\Omega=(0,1)$. Then $u_n \rightharpoonup 0$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ and weak-star in $L^\infty(\Omega)$. But $u_n^+$ does not converge weakly to zero, and $\int_\Omega u_n^+$ is constant and not equal to zero.

Comment: Yes you're right.